# How to get minutes between to dates?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have the following dates (`"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"` format) :

```
dateA = "2024-01-24T03:09:28.000523"
dateB = "2024-01-24T03:24:04.000719"
```

How can we get the difference between these two dates for a result in minutes ?

Comment: Note that unless you know the timezone, you cannot reliably do this, as DST could add or shave an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example for how the difference in minutes can be calculated:

```
from datetime import datetime

dateA = "2024-01-24T03:09:28.000523"
dateB = "2024-01-24T03:24:04.000719"

# Conversion of string to datetime object
A = datetime.strptime(dateA, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
B = datetime.strptime(dateB, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")

# Calculation of difference
diff = B - A

# Convert difference in seconds to minutes
minutes_diff = diff.total_seconds() / 60.0

print(minutes_diff)
```

Conversion of string to datetime object using datetime.fromisoformat

```
from datetime import datetime

dateA = "2024-01-24T03:09:28.000523"
dateB = "2024-01-24T03:24:04.000719"

A = datetime.fromisoformat(dateA)
B = datetime.fromisoformat(dateB)

# Calculation of difference
diff = B - A

# Convert difference in seconds to minutes
minutes_diff = diff.total_seconds() / 60.0

print(minutes_diff)
```

Comment: This could be simplified using `datetime.fromisoformat`

Comment: Absolutely 
`A = datetime.fromisoformat(dateA[:-3])`
`B = datetime.fromisoformat(dateB[:-3])`

Comment: What Python version requires the `[:-3]`? It's not needed in recent versions, they handle the microseconds fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.fromisoformat` to directly parse the ISO-formatted strings without specifying the format string.

```
from datetime import datetime

dateA = "2024-01-24T03:09:28.000523"
dateB = "2024-01-24T03:24:04.000719"

datetimeA = datetime.fromisoformat(dateA)
datetimeB = datetime.fromisoformat(dateB)

time_difference = datetimeB - datetimeA

minutes_difference = time_difference.total_seconds() / 60

print("Difference in minutes:", minutes_difference)
```